# Proof of merge sort time complexity when input size is not a power of 2?

Tags: sorting, time-complexity, big-o, mergesort

I'm aware that the time complexity of merge sort is O(nlogn), but every proof I have seen involves considering the running time of merge sort to be T(n) = 2T(n/2) + O(n) for n>1, and T(n) = O(1) for n=1. However, this recursion tree proof would only work when n is a power of 2, as T(n) is only defined on integers. What would the proof be for the more general case when we don't just assume the input size is a power of 2?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Imagine your input size is *n = 2<sup>m</sup> + k*, where *k < 2<sup>m</sup>*.

Then you can just add as many extra values to your list as you need to make the size *2<sup>m + 1</sup>* (padding), then sort this array and pluck your dummy values back out at the end. Now, your list indeed has the length of a power of two, so you can run mergesort the way you are used to, and in *O(2<sup>m + 1</sup> log(2<sup>m + 1</sup>))* time.

Well, *2<sup>m + 1</sup> = 2 * 2<sup>m</sup> <= 2n*, so your runtime is now *O(2n log(2n)) = O(n log n)*.

In conclusion, padding your list with enough values to turn it into a power of two will increase it with a factor *<2*, so by the properties of big-O notation, it is still in the same complexity class.